# use pre created Slim environment in different methods

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I am writing some tests with phpunit for several classes. each of the classes has the following method:

```
  function getDbh() {
    if ($this->dbh === null){
      $this->dbh = Slim::getInstance()->db->getConnection();
    }
    return $this->dbh;
  }
```

but the problem is that after the first test slim create this Environment singleton that i have no clue i can i use in following tests.

to make my specific issue a bit clearer, each of my test classes has this method:

```
public function testGetDbh_dbhIsNull()
{
    $fixture = new testedClass();

    $app = new Slim();
    $DB = $this->getMockBuilder('DB')
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->getMock();
    $DB->method('getConnection')->willReturn('connection');
    $app->db = $DB;

    $this->assertEquals($fixture->getDbh(), 'connection');
}
```

but from the second test, the test fails due to the following error:

```
1) GroupTest::testSlim
Failed asserting that 'connection' matches expected null.
```

any idea how can i use the Slim singleton in each of the tests? thx

Answer (score -1):

Your test is wrong :)

```
public function testGetDbh_dbhIsNull()
{
    $fixture = new testedClass();

    $app = new Slim();
    $DB = $this->getMockBuilder('DB')
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->getMock();
    $DB->method('getConnection')->willReturn('connection');
    $app->db = $DB;

    //This points to the wrong object... This should fix it
    $this->assertEquals($app->db, 'connection');
}
```

Comment: where exactly in your answer  `testedClass::getDbh()` is being tested? you are not calling it...